# XSLT: copying XMS to XML and updating the structure of a file

Tags: xslt, xml-parsing

I have an XML file with the element `<Database>` that has two child elements `<Patients> and <Hospitals>`. Each`<Patients>` has a child element `<Patient>`, which has a name specified as an attribute. Each hospital has an attribute name, for example: `<Hospital name="JR"`and a child element `<Patients>` that has child elements `<Patient name="XY">`

I would like to update the file by copying the structure of patients, but adding hospital information to then. Either as an additional attribute to the patient name, or as a child element. Any thoughts?

EDIT: Thank you Tim, here's the sample.

```
<Database>
<Patients>
    <Patient name="Salvatore"/>
    <Patient name="Luca"/>
</Patients>
<Hospitals>
    <Hospital name="JR">
        <Patients>
            <Patient name="Salvatore"/>
        </Patients>
    </Hospital>
    <Hospital name="LondonGeneral">
        <Patients>
            <Patient name="Luca"/>
        </Patients>
    </Hospital>
</Hospitals>
</Database>
```

Output should look like:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Database>
    <Patients>
        <Patient name="Salvatore" hospital="JR"/>
        <Patient name="Luca" hospital="LondonGeneral"/>
    </Patients>
    <Hospitals>
        <Hospital name="JR">
            <Patients>
                <Patient name="Salvatore"/>
            </Patients>
        </Hospital>
        <Hospital name="LondonGeneral">
            <Patients>
                <Patient name="Luca"/>
            </Patients>
        </Hospital>
    </Hospitals>
</Database>
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: This sounds straight-forward, but could you possible edit your question to show a small, but complete, sample of your XML (with the names changed to protect the innocent), and your expected output, just to ensure there is no misunderstanding with the question. Thanks!

Comment: Can the same patient belong to more than one hospital?  If so you might be better representing the relation as elements rather than as an attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that each patient name is contained within exactly one `Hospital` element, the following should work

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <xsl:key name="hospitalPatientByName"
           match="Hospital/Patients/Patient"
           use="@name" />

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Patient[not(ancestor::Hospital)]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
      <xsl:attribute name="hospital">
        <xsl:value-of select="key('hospitalPatientByName', @name)/ancestor::Hospital/@name" />
      </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here we process each top-level `Patient` element by looking up the corresponding `Patient` from under a `Hospital` element by the patient name, then pulling out the name of the containing hospital.

If the same named `Patient` might be under more than one `Hospital` then I'd use a child element rather than an attribute

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <xsl:key name="hospitalPatientByName"
           match="Hospital/Patients/Patient"
           use="@name" />

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Patient[not(ancestor::Hospital)]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('hospitalPatientByName', @name)/ancestor::Hospital" mode="in-patient" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Hospital" mode="in-patient">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*" /></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Given your sample input this would produce

```
<Database>
<Patients>
    <Patient name="Salvatore"><Hospital name="JR"/></Patient>
    <Patient name="Luca"><Hospital name="LondonGeneral"/></Patient>
</Patients>
<Hospitals>
    <Hospital name="JR">
        <Patients>
            <Patient name="Salvatore"/>
        </Patients>
    </Hospital>
    <Hospital name="LondonGeneral">
        <Patients>
            <Patient name="Luca"/>
        </Patients>
    </Hospital>
</Hospitals>
</Database>
```

If (say) Luca were also in the JR list of patients then you'd get both hospitals listed, i.e.

```
<Patient name="Luca">
  <Hospital name="JR"/>
  <Hospital name="LondonGeneral"/>
</Patient>
```

Comment: @MichalB.Kovac Glad to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow.  Note that when you get an answer that solves your problem it's good manners to mark the answer as "accepted" (using the tick mark to the left) so other people can see at a glance that the problem is already solved.